# dismiss keyboard from all view hierarchy programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, dismiss

I have view controller like screenshot below.

When I touch textfield, the keyboard shows up.
I want to dismiss keyboard when I tap,drag on any screen.

I tried to put this code in viewcontroller, but doesn't work.

```
    func dismissKey() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer( target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    endEditing(true)
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

but if I put this code in custom cell class type 1 ,it dismisses keyboard only when I tap on this cell.

how can I dismiss keyboard when I touch on any screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to dismiss keyboard in `UIViewController` try:

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? In which class? And I dont see any difference compare my code.

Comment: `view.endEditing(true)` in your view controller.